# Why does jQuery TimePicker not work in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-9

The timepicker of jQuery works on every webbrowser except in Internet Explorer, WHY? I use this version of jQuery: jquery.timepicker-1.1.0.min.js

```
function LoadDateTimePickers()
{
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['nl']);
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ showOn: "button" });
    $(".timepicker").timepicker({ timeFormat: "HH:mm", interval: 60 });
}
```

Thank you in advance!

HERE IS A DEMO: http://wvega.com/demos/225/jquery-timepicker-examples/

Comment: it's a known issue, looks like you should upgrade jQuery to 1.5.2 : http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=268

Comment: answer this question so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a known issue, looks like you should upgrade jQuery to 1.5.2:

[jquery-datepicker](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=268)